# http get request using angularjs

Tags: angularjs, httprequest, get-request

So I am trying to send `Get request` with **angularjs**

However I am getting this error

```
Error: Argument 'SimpleController' is not a function, got undefined
```

here is my code

```
var module = angular.module('myApp', []);

module.config(function ($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post['SOAPAction'] = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/UpdateListItems';
});

function SimpleController($scope,$http)
{
    $http({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/petstore/pets/list",
        method: "GET",
    })
    .success(function(data){
        console.log("SUCCESS");
        $scope.pets = data;
    }).error(function() {
        console.log("FAIL");
        console.log("data: "+data+"\nstatus: "+status+"\nheaders: "+headers+"\nconfig: "+config)
        $scope.pets = [ {"id":1,"name":"Angelfish","description":"Saltwater fish from Australia","category":"Fish","imageUrl":"fish1.jpg","price":10}];
    });
}
```

Comment: Please post `<html/>` as well, even better a http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @Abdel-Rahman Shoman, I noticed you've asked 4 questions and have not awarded an answer to anyone.  You should be awarding answers by clicking the checkmark next to the one that best answers your question so that future visitors can be helped.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of

> function SimpleController($scope,$http)...

try using

> module.controller('SimpleController',function($scope,$http){
>
> // function body
>
> });

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have an extra comma causing the invalid function:

```
$http({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/petstore/pets/list",
    method: "GET",  // <--- remove that comma
})
```

Comment: well yes you are right
but it does not make that difference, still not working

Comment: If you are getting an undefined error it is because you have some syntax issues.  Have you run your code through jslint?